# DynDNS to Server on Home Network is Slow From Same Network

Tags: networking, firewall

I have Nginx running on a Raspberry Pi at home.  I have a DynDNS name pointed to my network's WAN IP.  The router, an Arris NVG468MQ, is port forwarding 80 and 443 to that Pi.  If I'm on a machine in the same home network and I use the DynDNS name to hit the Pi, it is often, but not always very slow, taking at least a minute at the "Stalled," "Blocked," or "Initial Connection" stage depending on the browser.  A few other notes:

[image: Web Developer Tools screenshot of a stall.]

1. When the request does go through, that's when my request is logged in access.log, not during any of the above listed phases.
2. The IP Addressed logged in access.log is 192.168.1.1, my router's IP address.   It's as if the computer never left the network.
3. When I sign into a VPN from that workstation, the problem quickly goes away.

I'm suspecting there's some goofy switch I have to toggle on that server.  Any idea how to solve this? TIA!

Comment: The DynDNS name resolves to the WAN address, and you are trying to access it from the LAN. There is no guarantee that the port forwarding works at all in this situation. Use a network sniffer to check the traffic between the client and the router and between the router and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Is there any way around that?

Comment: We don't know what is delaying your network connection without more information. Please analyze the problem with a network sniffer like Whireshark or tcpdump, then [edit] your question and show what you found out. One way to avoid the problem is to configure a DNS server in your local network to resolve your DynDNS name to the internal IP address of your Raspberry Pi.